# Why updated not working on vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My code like this :

```
updated() {
    console.log('test')
},
```

Demo and full code like this : https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/58492/

I check on console, the result of console.log('test') not display

If I use mounted, it works

Why if I use updated, it does not work?

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure it's because it's on the root instance and not a component. What are you updating on the instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not actually updating anything, check out this JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/58496/

This data is your initial data so this will never trigger an update hook.

```
data: {
  message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
}
```

Once I change the initial data in the mounted lifecycle hook you see that the `updated` hook gets triggered.

Comment: So do you mean there should be updated data? If there is no updated data then the `updated` does not work?

Comment: From the documentation: `Updated: Called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and patched.` So you actually need to change the value of a data property. So yes, there should be updated data.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Another situation that can make updated() fail has to do with v-if.  If the initial value of v-if for a component is true, the updated() function works.  But updated() can fail if the initial value of v-if is false.